# UIColor and CIColor how do they compare and what is the purpose of having two of them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

Recently I encountered some code where trying to get the CIColor property of a UIColor fails. The UIColor was initialized as a simple [UIColor blackColor] and trying to get the CIColor of that raised an exception.

```
CIColor *aCIColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CIColor]; //fails
```

What is the difference between CIColor and UIColor and why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CIColor, like UIColor, is used to represent channel dimensions of a color.

The difference as the documentation puts it is:

> You use CIColor objects in conjunction with other Core Image classes,
>   such as CIFilter, CIContext,and CIImage, to take advantage of the
>   built-in Core Image filters when processing images.

From WWDC 2013:

> So, because, you know, and CIColor doesn't handle color spaces, it
>   won't do CMYK color, it won't do patterns.
>
> So, these are all things that you're going to lose.
>
> If you ever think that you're going to need that, then probably not
>   the right strategy.

An alternate way, other than what has been already answered before me, You could have created the CIColor by creating CGColor of Black UIColor like:

```
CIColor *color = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

Answer (score 4):

The doc says

> Initializes a Core Image color object using an AppKit color object.

So you need create `CIColor` from `NSColor` class

```
CIColor *aCIColor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
```

The diff between `UIColor` and `CIColor` in that `UIColor` from `UIKit` framework and using in **iOS**. From Doc `Available in iOS 2.0 and later`

> A UIColor object represents color and sometimes opacity (alpha value).
>   You can use UIColor objects to store color data, and during drawing
>   you can use them to set the current fill and stroke colors

`CIColor` from `CoreImage` framework and using in **Mac OSX** `Available in OS X v10.4 and later`

> The CIColor class contains color values and the color space for which
>   the color values are valid. You use CIColor objects in conjunction
>   with other Core Image classes, such as CIFilter, CIContext,and
>   CIImage, to take advantage of the built-in Core Image filters when
>   processing images.

Answer (score 0):

try this(swift version)

```
 var clcor = CIColor(color: UIColor.redColor())
```

obj :

```
CIColor *aCIColor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `CIColor` **property** on UIImage says:

> This property throws an exception if the color object was not initialized with a Core Image color.

So if you want to access a UIColor's CIColor, it needs to have been created from a CIColor in the first place.

On the other hand, you can make a new CIColor from any UIColor using the `initWithColor:` initializer:

```
CIColor *color = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:UIColor.blackColor];
```