# Create CIImage Pattern from image file

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image, uigraphicscontext, ciimage

I'm trying to understand what is the most **efficient** way to create a `CIImage` with a pattern, based on an image file.

```
let patternImage = UIImage(named: "pattern.png")
```

### ***The first approach I took:***

```
// First create UIColor pattern
let uiColorPattern = UIColor(patternImage: patternImage!) 

// Than init CIColor using the UIColor pattern object
let ciColorPattern = CIColor(color: uiColorPattern)

// Finally, create CIImage using the CIColor initialiser
let ciImagePattern = CIImage(color: ciColorPattern) //
```

Sadly, for unknown reason the CIImage is simply blank. I also tried applying `clampedToExtent()` and than cropping it but it still blank.

### ***The second approach I took (works but too slow):***

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size) // create context

patternImage?.drawAsPattern(in: rect) // draw pattern as 'UIImage'

let patternUIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() // fetch 'UIImage'

UIGraphicsEndImageContext() // end context

if let patternUIImage = patternUIImage {
     let ciImagePattern = CIImage(image: patternUIImage) // Create 'CIImage' using 'UIImage'
}
```

this method works but as I said, too slow.

---

In general, my intuition was that if I could make the first approach work, it'll be a lot more efficient than the second approach.

### **Any other approaches/suggestions would be highly appreciated!**

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the end result? How large is the pattern?

Comment: Hey @meaning-matters . Thank you for replying. I need the CIImage to feed AVMutableVideoComposition->applyingCIFiltersWithHandler. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronousciimagefilteringrequest). The pattern image file is very small. But eventually the final rect i'll be applying it is about UIScreen bounds. Would love some assist over here :)

Comment: So are you applying this "pattern" over a strict bounds, or an infinite one? Have you actually tried any CIFIlter generators?

Comment: @dfd Yes, a strict bounds. (Let's assume I'm using UIScreen.main.bounds as my rect). I'm not trying CIFilter generator because I'm using file-based pattern. If there is a CIFilter that accept image as input and than generates CIImage pattern, it'll be perfect but I haven't found one

Comment: Hey @meaning-matters, Just PM'ing in case my comment didn't appear

Comment: Hey @dfd, Just PM'ing in case my comment didn't appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach you are taking would not work as 
From WWDC 2013:

> So, because, you know, and CIColor doesn't handle color spaces, it
>   won't do CMYK color, it won't do patterns.
>
> So, these are all things that you're going to lose.
>
> If you ever think that you're going to need that, then probably not
>   the right strategy.

So the second approach is what we can optimise on. I have a snippet which returns a pattern image you can give it a try.

```
        let myImage = UIImage.init(named: "www")
        let imageSize = myImage?.size
        let imageWidth = imageSize?.width
        let imageHeight = imageSize?.height
        let widthIterations = self.view.bounds.size.width / imageWidth!
        let heightIterations = self.view.bounds.size.height / imageHeight!

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()


            for i in 0 ... Int(heightIterations) {
                let yPoint = CGFloat(i) * imageHeight!
                for j in 0 ... Int(widthIterations) {
                    let xPoint = CGFloat(j) * imageWidth!
                    myImage?.draw(at: CGPoint.init(x: xPoint, y: yPoint))
                }
            }
        let tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

[image]

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889058/5807290)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for responding. Look's promising. Can you explain how and (approximately) in how much your snippet is more efficient than what I've attached?

Comment: I am not sure if its more efficient both of are doing the same thing behind the scenes

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty for the CIImage pattern reference. I think both of our solutions are the same :)

Comment: @RoiMulia Thanks :)